# Passing path to CreateProcessA

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a function, that reads a registry key, get a path for a program there, and call a CreateProcessA with this path as second parameter. Debugging the application, it fails saying that the file was not found.

a) yes, the file exists
b) yes, i have access to execute the file

Question: The function that actually reads the reg key and give the path to CreateProcessA, doesn't escape the path: it means, CreateProcessA receives a string like "C:\Program Files\prog.exe" and not like "C:\\Program Files\\prog.exe". Is that the problem? Does exist any Windows Function to escape all backslashes automatically?

Comment: Like "C:\Program Files\prog.exe" and not like "C:\Program Files\prog.exe"? They are the same.

Comment: @rasmus stackoverflow filtered two backslashes. i had to escape it :)

Comment: Three possibilities:  1) your code is broken, 2) the registry key is incorrect, or 3) the file simply does not exist.  With no code and no data, it's impossible for anyone to guess which it is.

Comment: Escapiing of the `\` is only needed in path string literals. They do not exist in the actual string and they should never be added programitcally or passed to the Win32 API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common errors include not specifying the path to the executable as the first argument to CreateProcess, and not quoting the path to the executable in the second argument

```
CreateProcess( <exe path goes here> , <quoted exe path plus parameters goes here>, ... );
```

Like so:

```
std::wstring executable_string(_T("c:\\program files\\myprogram\\executable.exe"));
std::wstring parameters(_T("-param1 -param2"));

wchar_t path[MAX_PATH+3];
PathCanonicalize(path, executable_string.c_str());
path[sizeof(path)/sizeof(path[0]) - 1] = _T('\0');

// Make sure that the exe is specified without quotes.
PathUnquoteSpaces(path);
const std::wstring exe = path;

// Make sure that the cmdLine specifies the path to the executable using
// quotes if necessary.
PathQuoteSpaces(path);
std::wstring cmdLine = path + std::wstring(_T(" ")) + parameters;

BOOL res = CreateProcess(
                 exe.c_str(),
                 const_cast<wchar_t *>(cmdLine.c_str()),
                 ...);
```

I just copied and adapted some, so there might be some errors in the above, but the idea is there. Make sure to use path without quotes in the first parameter and path with quotes in the second and you should be fine.

Comment: ok, but i see that you are using Unicode. As I specified, i'm using the Ansi version CreateProcessA. My question was: i'm reading a path from the registry. the path hasn't "\\" but "\". should I escape the backslash?

Comment: @VP: You don't need to escape the backslash you read from the registry. The "\\" in the example here is needed for the C compiler to be able to put a single \ in a string. The string passed to CreateProcessA() is `c:\program files\myprogram\executable.exe`

Comment: @VP: tinman is 100% correct here. There should be no difference with running the ANSI version, except that 1. you need to use std::string in the example above, 2. you won't be able to use paths that have non-ansi characters in them, 3. I think you might get away without the const cast then.

Comment: The first argument is optional and need not be provided at all as long as it's provided in the second argument.

Comment: @CareyGregory: That is true. However, I have found that there is less chance of error if you do provide it in the first argument as well. If you don't you _must_ make sure that the path to the executable is quoted in the second argument to avoid errors with paths containing white spaces. Also, you _must_ use the first parameter if the path to the executable is more than MAX_PATH characters (note that I don't believe the above example handles that). I believe that the docs for CreateProcess recommends the use of the first parameter (to avoid the white space issue).

Comment: my problem is exactly that. I'm passing NULL as first parameter and the full path as second.. and it fails..

Comment: @VP: Do you make sure to quote the path to the executable? If your executable is c:\program files\prog.exe, CreateProcess will do things like attempt to start c:\program.exe with the parameters files\prog.exe. See documentation for CreateProcess: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx .